# Why can't cython memory views be pickled?

Tags: cython, memoryview

I have a cython module that uses memoryview arrays, that is...

```
double[:,:] foo
```

I want to run this module in parallel using multiprocessing. However I get the error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'tile_class._memoryviewslice'>: attribute lookup tile_class._memoryviewslice failed
```

Why can't I pickle a memory view and what can I do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe passing the actual array instead of the memory view can solve your problem. 
If you want to execute a function in parallel, all of it parameters have to be picklable if i recall correctly. At least that is the case with python multiprocessing. So you could pass the array to the function and create the memoryview inside your function.

```
def some_function(matrix_as_array):
    cdef double[:,:] matrix = matrix_as_array
    ...
```

I don't know if this helps you, but I encountered a similar problem. I use a memoryview as an attribute in a cdef class. I had to write my own [`__reduce__`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce__) and [`__setstate__`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html#object.__setstate__) methods to correctly unpickle instances of my class. Pickling the memory view as an array by using `numpy.asarray` and restoring it in `__setstate__` worked for me. A reduced version of my code:

```
import numpy as np

cdef class Foo:
    cdef double[:,:] matrix

    def __init__(self, matrix):
        '''Assign a passed array to the typed memory view.'''
        self.matrix = matrix

    def __reduce__(self):
        '''Define how instances of Foo are pickled.'''
        d=dict()
        d['matrix'] = np.asarray(self.matrix)
        return (Foo, (d['matrix'],), d)

    def __setstate__(self, d):
        '''Define how instances of Foo are restored.'''
        self.matrix = d['matrix']
```

Note that `__reduce__` returns a tuple consisting of a callable (`Foo`), a tuple of parameters for that callable (i.e. what is needed to create a 'new' Foo instance, in this case the saved matrix) and the dictionary with all values needed to restore the instance.