# Django import export - Unable to import model with BinaryField

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm trying to import data from a model which has nullable `BinaryField`. The data doesn't contain the field and I want it to be imported with a null value in the field. If the field already exists in the database for a given `id`, it should keep the value as it is.

I removed the field from the `fields` whitelist in the corresponding `Resource` object and added it to the `exclude` blacklist. However, I'm getting this error while importing - `can't pickle memoryview objects`.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 451, in import_row
original = deepcopy(instance)
File "/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 182, in deepcopy
y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
File "/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 297, in _reconstruct
state = deepcopy(state, memo)
File "/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 155, in deepcopy
y = copier(x, memo)
File "/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 243, in _deepcopy_dict
y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
File "/lib/python3.5/copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle memoryview objects
```

Package versions - django==1.11, django-import-export==0.6

EDIT:

```
class ABC(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)
    binary_field = models.BinaryField('Some name', null=True, blank=True)

class ABCResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = ABC
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
        )
        import_id_fields = ('id',)
        exclude = ('binary_field',)

class ABCAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    form = ABCModelForm
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'name',
    )
    exclude = ('binary_field',)
    resource_class = ABCResource

class ABCModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ABC
        exclude = ['binary_field']
```

Comment: Proprietary code, so added a reduced version of it...

Comment: what version of `django-import-export` are you using?

Comment: django-import-export is 0.6

Comment: brain-fart, sorry.  @Roshan does this occur with the latest 0.7 release?

Comment: I tried this using for django 1.11 and django-import-export==0.5.1 but I haven't faced any issues.

Comment: tried with 0.7. Same issue

Comment: please provide forms.py and admin.py also

Comment: Added ModelForm

Comment: For what it's worth, I was not able to recreate your issue using for same version of django and django-import-export. django-import-export ignores the BinaryField when it's missing from the fields list or included in the exclude list, as expected, and never attempt to serialize the memoryview, because it never creates an instance of a model with one populated.

Comment: It's really a huge waste of resources, time and effort to use django import export or to even attempt to dump a database at application level at all. Use the tools that are custom made for this - that is your databases dump tool.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly this seems to be a problem with [`django-import-export`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export) module.

In Python 2.7+ and 3.5.2+, pickling `memoryview` objects, is permitted. Try the following code just to confirm that:

```
import pickle

test = memoryview(b'abc')
test.__reduce__()
```

The above will raise the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle memoryview objects
```

Apparently, in line 451 of django-import-export (version 0.6), the `BinaryField` is passed as a `memoryview` object to

```
original = deepcopy(instance)
```

which causes the error (`instance` contains the BinaryField as a `memoryview` object).
In the current version (1.0.0) this happens in line [446](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L446).

The instance retrieved/generated by the [`instance_loader`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/instance_loaders.py) of the module doesn't take into consideration the `BinaryField`.

You should probably open a ticket at [`django-import-export`](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export) about this.

Answer (score 0):

have you added `binary_field` in `ABCModelForm` ? If yes, then it is creating issue because It is not possible to include a BinaryField in a ModelForm. For reference : [binaryfield](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield)

Comment: No, I have `exclude = ['binary_field']` in the ModelForm's Meta class

Answer (score 0):

Maybe passing the actual array instead of the memory view can solve your problem. If you want to execute a function in parallel, all of it parameters have to be picklable if i recall correctly. At least that is the case with python multiprocessing. So you could pass the array to the function and create the memoryview inside your function.

reference: [moreinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22252368/3553893)

Comment: Um, I'm not passing a memoryview anywhere. It's probably done implicitly by django-import-export

Comment: The memoryview is created in BinaryFields.to_python method: <https://github.com/django/django/blob/d368784bacc7e58b426f29937ee842aa14d439ad/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2342> The link is from the current head, but the behavior has been consistent for awhile.